# Google App Engine backend with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying out a GAE based backend using the sample code on the page below:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Have been able to deploy the backend and I can view & execute the APIs on API explorer through appspot.com link - project-id.appspot.com

When I execute the client app (Android based) and call 
         `regService.register(regId).execute();`
On the server side I get the following log entry on Google Developer Console -

```
"POST /registration/v1/registerDevice/APA91bHCCvjkMFdvf6YHh_rbdqdKMYoRnwm6iswQtTpztwCfNVWq_7xwSq1y9naiipYmfTrREInybypeLb5mc7LCzYGBSpC9jFM-Co_6xGUBiEjLyo1UT375ak7p0nrOiTdHFNwW7r31WYQJP7ojigRLxBTYvST4XTeNIufD6GHb3SbDFGl1hsc HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - "20773xxxxxxx Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)" "verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com" ms=19 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.9.7 trace_id=ddfbcf4e13e27e2aa2a6c5e77bb8cc6f
```

where:

1. registration/v1/registerDevice/ are API/version/Method of the backend service
2. `APA91bHCCvjkMFdvf6YHh_rbdqdKMYoRnwm6iswQtTpztwCfNVWq_7xwSq1y9naiipYmfTrREInybypeLb5mc7LCzYGBSpC9jFM-Co_6xGUBiEjLyo1UT375ak7p0nrOiTdHFNwW7r31WYQJP7ojigRLxBTYvST4XTeNIufD6GHb3SbDFGl1hsc`
   .. is the device registration id returned by gcm.register(SENDER_ID); gcm is of type GoogleCloudMessaging

`20773xxxxxxx or SENDER_ID` is the Project number provided on the Google Developer Console.
& verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com is the Project Id.

Can you please tell me why am I getting HTTP/1.1 404 in the response?

Thanks in advance..

---

Sharing the building of regService --

```
public class GcmRegistrationAsync extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String> {
private Registration regService;    // A Stub API from Server
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private Context context;

// TODO: change to your own sender ID to Google Developers Console project 
// number, as per instructions above
private static final String SENDER_ID = "20773xxxxxxx";

public void GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(int i) {
    Registration.Builder builder = new  Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
    // Need setRootUrl and setGoogleClientRequestInitializer only for local testing, 
    // otherwise they can be skipped
    .setRootUrl("https://verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com")
    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
        }
    });

    i = this.test();
    builder.setApplicationName(SENDER_ID);
    regService = builder.build();
}

public int test () {
    return 1;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
    int i = params.length;
    context = (Context) params[0];

    String msg = "test";
    try {
        if (gcm == null) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        }
        String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

        // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
        // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
        // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
        // is using accounts.
        regService.register(regId).execute();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        msg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

}

In MyActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
:
:
    gcmRegistrationAsync = new GcmRegistrationAsync();
    gcmRegistrationAsync.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(1);
    gcmRegistrationAsync.execute(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you "build" the regService?

Answer (score 2):

To connect to an endpoint you have to connect with `https`, if you connect with `http` like you did (in your setUrl) then you get the 404 error.

Also your code can probably look more like :

```
Registration.Builder builder = new  Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);
```

The rootUrl doesn't need be set, by default it uses your appspot location, when running locally, it's useful to direct the endpoint to your devapp server (app engine local testing server).

The code that disables compression is also just used to be compatible with the devapp server

Comment: I tried the same but got "404 Not Found" without any other detail in the error message. With https in setUrl the same detailed error appears again..

Comment: and you can still access via api explorer?

Comment: Yes I can access through https://verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer and can run those APIs

Comment: So if api explorer is working, it looks like your issues are definitely on the JAVA client side. Did the error have any slight differences when you you changed the builder?

Comment: yes, with the following I just get "404 Not Found" Registration.Builder builder = new  Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);

Comment: but when I try to build by using setRootUrl then the error is more descriptive - "POST /registration/v1/registerDevice/APA91bHCCvjkMFdvf6YHh_rbdqdKMYoRnwm6iswQtTpztwCfNVWq_7xwSq1y9naiipYmfTrREInybypeLb5mc7LCzYGBSpC9jFM-Co_6xGUBiEjLyo1UT375ak7p0nrOiTdHFNwW7r31WYQJP7ojigRLxBTYvST4XTeNIufD6GHb3SbDFGl1hsc HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - "20773xxxxxxx Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)" "verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com" ms=19 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.9.7 trace_id=ddfbcf4e13e27e2aa2a6c5e77bb8cc6f

Comment: Did you set an app id in your appengine-web.xml when you generated the client libraries? Because that gets baked into the endpoint at generation. Also I missed this earlier, but when using setRootUrl you have to include the full endpoints URL : "https://verlllll-auyyyy-zzz.appspot.com/_ah/api/" (with https)

Comment: I tried putting in HTTP instead of HTTPS in the setRootUrl now and it does give you a 404 error. Once I amended it to HTTPS the error went away.

Comment: I am not able to import `Registration` any suggestion?