# How to register android device for receiving Push notifications via App Engine backend?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have created the sample android project with Android app and App Engine as a backend using [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints). But on the step 2.4, I am stuck in showing push notifications from GCM backend. When I debug, I found that there are 0 registered device in my RegistrastionRecord. So, how to correctly register the app for receiving push notifications using App Engine local backend?

I got this error:

```
Failed to complete token refresh  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
                                                                     <html><head><title>Error 404</title></head>
                                                                     <body><h2>Error 404</h2></body>
                                                                     </html>
```

Here is my Registration Endpoint:

```
@Api(
    name = "registration",
    version = "v1",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.Mikhail.example.com",
            ownerName = "backend.myapplication.Mikhail.example.com",
            packagePath=""
    )
 )
  public class RegistrationEndpoint {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationEndpoint.class.getName());

/**
 * Register a device to the backend
 *
 * @param regId The Google Cloud Messaging registration Id to add
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId) {
    if (findRecord(regId) != null) {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
        return;
    }
    RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
    record.setRegId(regId);
    ofy().save().entity(record).now();
}

/**
 * Unregister a device from the backend
 *
 * @param regId The Google Cloud Messaging registration Id to remove
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "unregister")
public void unregisterDevice(@Named("regId") String regId) {
    RegistrationRecord record = findRecord(regId);
    if (record == null) {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " not registered, skipping unregister");
        return;
    }
    ofy().delete().entity(record).now();
}

/**
 * Return a collection of registered devices
 *
 * @param count The number of devices to list
 * @return a list of Google Cloud Messaging registration Ids
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "listDevices")
public CollectionResponse<RegistrationRecord> listDevices(@Named("count") int count) {
    List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(count).list();
    return CollectionResponse.<RegistrationRecord>builder().setItems(records).build();
}

private RegistrationRecord findRecord(String regId) {
    return ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).filter("regId", regId).first().now();
}
```

}

Here is the sendRegistrationToServer(). I call it from onHandleIntent() from RegistrationIntentService:

```
   private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) throws IOException {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.

    Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            // Need setRootUrl and setGoogleClientRequestInitializer only for local testing,
            // otherwise they can be skipped
            .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")

            .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                        throws IOException {
                    abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                }
            });
    Registration regService = builder.build();
    regService.register(token).execute();

    //regService.register(token).execute();
}
```

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563913/googlejsonresponseexception-404-not-found-using-google-apps-endpoint-engine-bac ie.you may be missing application id at appengine-web.xml

Comment: Do you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem for long. After I upgrade the plugin all libraries to the latest version, it works so fine for me.

Plugin:

`classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'`

Libraries:

```
ext {
    appEngineVersion = '1.9.38'
}

dependencies {
    appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:${appEngineVersion}"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:${appEngineVersion}"
    compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:${appEngineVersion}"
    ...
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error **Failed to complete token refresh  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found** because a resource associated with the request could not be found. Please re-deploy the App Engine app and try calling it again.

Based from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989851/google-app-engine-backend-with-google-cloud-messaging), you have to connect with `https` to connect to an endpoint, if you connect with `http` in your `setRootUrl` then you may get the 404 error. When using `setRootUrl`, you have to include the full endpoints URL with `https`. You also need to set an app id in your appengine-web.xml when you generated the client libraries. That gets back into the endpoint at generation.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957391/android-mobile-backend-starter-fail-with-404-not-found-some-times) might also help.